# Access Spring Web Flow snapshot version using Maven

Tags: spring, jsf, maven, spring-webflow

I need to try the current snapshot version 2.3.1 of Spring Web Flow in my project, hoping it will fix [this bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1461) for me. I have read the documentation on [how to access nightly builds](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ch01s07.html) and added the following to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the repository needed:

```
    <repository>
        <id>org.springsource.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>SpringSource Maven Central-compatible Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
```

But when I try a `mvn clean install` maven fails to resolve the dependencies:

*[ERROR] ... The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT ...

Am I missing something obvious? Am I using the wrong snapshot version? Is there a way to list the contents of the snapshot repository? Any hints are appreciated...

P.S.: I cross-posted this question on the SpringSource community forum and will of course post the answer here if I get it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find the version of the snap shot you have in the dependency, Here are all the web flow snap shot down loads that I can see from spring source site http://static.springsource.org/downloads/nightly/snapshot-download.php?project=SWF

If you change the version tag in you'r pom.xml that will resolve the issue.

```
<version>2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much! I assumed (by mistake) that version 2.3.0.RELEASE was newer than 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and that 2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT would preceded 2.3.1.RELEASE.